# How do I check the state of JQuery slide toggles?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

So I have an accordion menu to display results and a "Show All" button at the top so that the user doesn't have to click each one to expand it. When they click "Show All", all of the content expands out, and the button's text switches to say "Hide All".

However, I want to make sure that if the user decides to manually close all of the sections himself, then the button will switch from "Hide All" to "Show All" again.

I'd like this to work the other way too, just in case they open all of them (or perhaps any number of them). It'd be nice if I could get the button to then say "Hide All".

Make sense? It should be relatively simple...I'm just new to JQuery, and I'm not sure how to check the state of the toggle. Here's the code I have to expand all of the sections.

```
    function expandAll() {
        if(document.getElementById("displayMajors").innerHTML == "Show All") {
            $('.accordionContent').slideDown('normal');
            document.getElementById("displayMajors").innerHTML = "Hide All";
        }
        else { 
            $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
            document.getElementById("displayMajors").innerHTML = "Show All";
        }
     }
```

"displayMajors" is the ID of the button, and "accordionContent" is a div class.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with plain JavaScript like that? Also, can you post the rest of your code and the HTML?

Comment: if you're using jQuery, I'd stick to using selectors with `$('.something')` instead of raw js

Comment: @j08691 I haven't done it before, so I found a script that closely accomplished that I was looking for, and made modifications. I know javascript, and so I figured I could just combine the two. If there's a better way, by all means let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a test function

```
function test_accordion() {
    var elems = $('.accordionContent');
    if (elems.filter(':visible').length == 0) // all hidden
        $("#displayMajors").html("Show All");
    else if (elems.filter(':hidden').length == 0) // all visible
        $("#displayMajors").html("Hide All");
}
```

Whenever you slide an element up (or down), add the test function as the callback function. It will be executed when the animation's finished completely:

```
$(some_element).slideUp(test_accordion);
$(some_element).slideDown(test_accordion);
```

Comment: It's taking some finagling, but I think I got it.